# Java. Spring. How to register own class-name property

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, configurationproperties

I'm already several days looks for way to define in my properties class (that annotated as @ConfigurationProperties) string property that will be name of class, that implement specified interface. Like an spring.datasource.driver-class-name.

If your code contains java.sql.Driver implementation (or you have several dependensies with impls) then when you edit application.properties file, idea helps you to choose driver from list of implementations

I want the same.

I put completed project here: https://github.com/ibelozor/test-spring-properties (kotlin, gradle)

i define service:

```
interface MyService {
    fun doSomething()
}
```

, implementation[s]:

```
class ServiceAImpl: MyService {
    override fun doSomething()  {
        println("Do something implementation from ${this.javaClass.name}")
    }
}
```

, properties:

```
/**
 * Service properties
 */
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service")
data class MyServiceProps (
        /**
         * Device driver class name
         */
        var className: String = "ru.ibelozor.test.classname.DefaultServiceImpl"
) {
        fun getService(): MyService {
                val serviceClass = Class.forName(className)
                return MyService::class.java.cast(serviceClass.newInstance())
        }
}
```

, so i can use my service as bean (and this works great):

```
@Configuration
class TestConfig
@Autowired constructor(private val props: MyServiceProps) {
    @Bean
    fun getMyService(): MyService {
        return props.getService()
    }
}
```

But i want that idea suggest me implementations of my interface when i edit an application.properties file

case of spring.datasource.driver-class-name:
[image: case of spring.datasource.driver-class-name]


my case - service.class-name=... No suggestions:
[image: my case - service.class-name=... No suggestions]

Comment: Works for me out of the box.

Comment: maybe the question was not correctly asked (i have problems with english=)? i updated description

Comment: Ok, you have a properties file, within this properties file you have a property `service.class-name` (or similiar) and in your code you use the value of this property to create instances of the `MyService` interface. And now you want your IDE (I suppose it is IntelliJ??) to propose you the classnames of different implementations of this interface that are available in your classpath, when editing the properties file??

Comment: yep. that's what i want